# How do I get money in the Wasteland?

Tags: wasteland

I'm playing back through the original Wasteland game, in anticipation of the kickstarted sequel. With all the strategy guides around, most of it is easy and rewarding, but I'm stuck for how to get money once the game has started.

All the old walkthroughs say to make junk characters and sell their gear to load up on cash before the game even starts, but I'm a bit into the game now and didn't do that. I'm loathe to delete my characters just to sell off gear for cash.

What ways are there to make money inside the game? It's so very different to play an RPG where the random encounters don't drop a few coppers.

Comment: Since when is there money in Wasteland? Just get some weapon and you are good to go.

Comment: There's money. You don't need much once you get going, but it's handy in the early game to buy bullet proof shirts for each member of the party, and later to get the AT weapons you sold for operating cash early back out of hock.

Comment: That's the best method I've found so far (thanks to spoilers): Sell off the LAW rockets you get for attacking the Savage Village early.

Answer (score 4):

Exploring new areas will yield you lots of loot to sell. In the beginning try the caves, ag center and Rail Nomads camp, then Quartz & Needles.

The beginning of the game is fairly loot-light, but once you get any sort of armor you can reduce your usage of ammo and defeat most enemies using Hand-to-Hand fighting. This means that you will have lots more ammo to sell.

Once you are on to the middle and later areas you will be mostly swimming in loot and/or money. The hard part will be finding a place that sells the equipment you want (most of the best gear is found, not purchased).

Once you have few thousand that you don't need to spend, you can gamble (at the Rail nomads is best) with one character with the Gamble skill & high luck. Once you get to gamble skill 5+ you will come out ahead. If you end up getting gambling to a high enough level than you can exploit the skill-point allocation wraparound bug: you gain skill points for allocating high levels of a skill at a library if the skill would cost more than 255 points to allocate.